# Correct values for current limiting resistors for motor driver (DRV8834) control lines

Tags: resistors, stepper-motor, current-limiting

I would like to control a DRV8834 Dual-Bridge Stepper Motor driver in 'indexer' mode, where only two digital lines are needed (M1STP or STEP_BENABLE and M1DIR or DIR_BPHASE in the image below).

[image]

According to the driver's manual (image below) the typical logic input high current should be 16.5 micro Amps.

[image]

I'm planning on using a PIC32MX170F256 which should give me 3.3 Volts on the output lines (that's the pic's VDD) so I figure I need 200 kOhm resistors:

(3.3V / 16.5 mA) = 200kOhm

How is it that the DRV8834 Evaluation Module is only using 3.3kOhm resistors?  Am I missing something really basic here? The microcontroller that the evaluation module is using (MSP430F2617) is also running on 3.3V. The image below is from the Evaluation Module's User's Guide. I would really appreciate if somebody could help clear this up.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think you need resistors at all?

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, really. Are they not necessary? I would wonder why the eval module is using them then...

Comment: @sage6 I'm not going to read the datasheet closely, so this is only a guess. I suspect they are there to create a defined output impedance and to dampen parasitic oscillation.

Comment: Those resistors might be there in order to protect the microcontroller in case you accidentally connect an output directly to something low-impedance. (I have a Raspberry Pi where I've accidentally connected a HIGH output directly to ground, several times! Now I'm using resistors to protect the Pi in case I do it again.)

Comment: @sage6 They don't *hurt*, but they aren't necessary, no.

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know! I guess I was making too much ado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

200 kOhm resistors won't (necessarily) work. If you're feeding 3.3 V into the resistor, and the DRV8834 tries to pull 16.5 μA through that resistor, then the DRV8834 will end up seeing 0 V on that pin, and so it won't read it as high.

On the other hand, 3.3 kOhm resistors would be just fine. If the DRV8834 pulls 16.5 μA through one of those resistors, then the voltage across the resistor will only be about 0.054 V. If the input voltage is 3.3 V, then the DRV8834 will still see more than 3.2 V there, and so it will read that as high.

Alternatively, you can leave the resistor out. If you apply 3.3 V directly to that input pin, and the DRV8834 operates correctly, it will still pull no more than 33 μA of current.

Comment: Thank you kindly! I will switch to the 3.3kOhm resistors